# Error: "use of moved value"

Tags: scope, rust

I'm currently learning Rust, and am toying around with a simple calculator. When refactoring, I ended up with some code like the following:

```
enum OptionalToken {
    Foo,
    Bar
}

fn next_token() -> OptionalToken {
    // Read input, classify, return
    OptionalToken::Foo
}


trait Stack {
    // ...
    fn dump (mut self);
}

impl Stack for Vec<f64> {
    // ...
    fn dump (mut self) {
        println!("Stack: size={} [", self.len());
        for x in self.iter() {
            println!("   {}", x);
        };
        println!("]");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut stack: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();

    loop {
        let tok = next_token();
        match tok {
            OptionalToken::Foo => { stack.dump(); }
            OptionalToken::Bar => { stack.pop(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler (nightly build) fails with the following error (same error is actually printed twice as I'm doing the same mistake twice):

```
src/test.rs:38:37: 38:42 error: use of moved value: `stack`
src/test.rs:38             OptionalToken::Foo => { stack.dump(); }
                                                   ^~~~~
src/test.rs:38:37: 38:42 note: `stack` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<f64>`, which is non-copyable
src/test.rs:38             OptionalToken::Foo => { stack.dump(); }
```

What am I doing wrong here? What would I have to modify to get code structured like this to work?

Comment: In addition to [The Rust Programming Language](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book) (specifically the chapter on [ownership](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html)), there's a *bunch* of questions about "use of moved value" here on SO. It'd be a good idea if you linked to these references and state what you didn't understand about them. That lets us know that you've done appropriate research and could let us improve the references as well.

Answer (score 2):

The function signature `fn dump(mut self)` (or `fn dump(self)`, it makes no difference and frankly I'm surprised that the `mut` is permitted in the trait) means that the method takes the `Stack` by value, i.e. moves it.

There is no reason to take ownership. Make the signature `fn dump(&self)` to be able to call it without moving.

If "moving" is is all Greek to you, see the [Ownership](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html) chapter in TRPL.

Comment: "it makes no difference" - sure it does. ^_^ Try compiling `fn foo(mut a: u8) { a += 1; }` without the `mut`. It's not *necessary*, because you can always reassign it with the `mut` modifier, and I think it's better practice to *not* have it, but it certainly changes things.

Comment: @Shepmaster but it seems you can compile `trait Stack { fn dump(self); }` with `impl Stack for SomeType { fn dump(mut self) {...} }`. So really "no difference" in the _trait_.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski interesting - it also compiles if you switch it the other way around, putting the `mut` on the trait declaration. I suppose this is just a convenience for the implementer of the trait then.

Comment: @Shepmaster not sure - the other way around it doesn't compile for me if I really use mutability in the impl (unless I rebind with `mut` inside the method body, of course).